# Reassigning prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there anyway to reassign an instance object's prototype?

Something like this:

```
var parent = {prop: 'parent.prop'};

var child = Object.create(parent);

child.prototype = {prop: 'other'};

child.prop; // 'other'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only with the non-standard `__proto__` property, which I believe is deprecated in the environments that support it.

```
child.__proto__ = {prop: 'other'};
```

Comment: BAD. Mutable prototypes are the devil. Never do this

Comment: @Raynos: Not even [as a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804881/emulating-pass-by-reference-in-javascript) in certain cases? ;)

Comment: I knew i was committing grevious evil there.